# Slanted div border transparency

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So, I know how to make slanted divs using :after and borders for modern layouts.

But, I'm wondering if you can use this to crop out a portion of a div through transparency? For example, lets say I had a row of cards with background images and I wanted the slanted effect on these. but, the slant here is just a transparency layer to where the page (not background image of the cards) would bleed through.

Using `border-color: (color) transparent transparent` won't work. Nor will the reverse for either slanted direction. Not sure how to go about this or if it's even possible.

```css
.row > div {
  background: url("https://www.google.com/photos/about/static/images/google.svg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  }

body{ background: orange;}
    
  .row > div:first-child::after {
  content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    top: 0;
    border-width: 90px 0 0 100vw;
    border-color: black transparent transparent;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='row'>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Web is virtual space. *Anything* is possible. But without a [mcve] your question is quite unclear.

Comment: It's not exactly confusing, but definitely not as clear as you think.  You're talking about rows and columns as if it should be obvious to us what you mean but there are about 15 different ways to make rows and columns in a web layout.  If you could provide the example Andrei requested we could help you.  Use the snippet  feature of Stack Overflow (it's quite cool) and it's the button with "<>" inside of it.  It allows you to edit HTML, JS, and CSS and we could then see what you've already tried to accomplish your goals.

Comment: @MatthewLudwig See snippet. So instead of the black bar "slant" it'd be transparency "cutting" the content out of the div. The rows and columns are irrelevant here. Basically, how to make the body content bleed through with a transparent overlay is what I'm after.

Comment: So you want to draw a whole in your element, whatever it might contain, and that whole should be transparent? See through?

Comment: Yes. That's correct.

Comment: @DjangoTango wow looks like it'd be pretty cool if possible.  I'm glad you got some answers on the question now that it's been updated.  Good luck with whatever you're working on!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, you can't trim the element's content using `border`.

The HTML `border` is a painted surface at the edge of the element and it's pretty limited regarding shape. The only neat trick you can do with border is using images and get the middle section to auto-repeat.
And, of course, you can round borders, using `border-radius`.

But if you want a non-rectangular you need to use either HTML elements or pseudo-elements.

However, one **can** trim element contents, using [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path):

```css
.row>div {
  background: url(https://www.google.com/photos/about/static/images/google.svg) no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
  padding-bottom: 33%;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 42%, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
}

body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/800/600) no-repeat 50% 50% /cover;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class='row'>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Do*** note browser support is currently sitting [at 88%](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path). If you want more, you're better off cutting your text in the image editor of your choice and saving the result as `<svg>`.

For more on clipping and masking I recommend these articles:

- https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/
- https://css-tricks.com/masking-vs-clipping-use/